# View Field, Insert View, View Reference, Block Reference, Insert Block: which to choose to embed a view in a page

Tags: views

I have a view I would like to embed in a page with some other content. The page is for logged-in users only. I could make a page or a block version of the view. I could make a new content type or not for the page- it's not a big deal. So I could use [Viewfield](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewfield), [Insert View](https://www.drupal.org/project/insert_view), [View Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/viewreference), [Block Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/blockreference), [Insert Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/insert_block), [EVA](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva), and maybe some others to embed the view. I could even code a page template up with `views_embed_view()`, though I would prefer to use an existing module for ease of future maintenance. Using the view's header and footer fields is inadequate in this case, because I want the surrounding content to be easily editable?

Are there technical reasons to choose one of these modules over the others? For instance, do any of them have issues with caching or permissions? Or, for instance, Is there a reason not to use the view as a block?

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

Just create a page for the view.

You can set which permission or role should have access to the page.

If you need to display content above or below the view use the header and footer.

**Option 2**

Use [`hook_node_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_view/7) and [`views_embed_view()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7) to add the view as a field to the node you want to target:

```
function hook_node_view($node, $view_mode, $langcode) {

  // Add whatever logic you want here to only target the nodes you want
  if($some_check == TRUE) {
    // Add a new field to the content array
    $node->content['view_field'] = array(
      // Render you view
      "#markup"=> views_embed_view('view_name', 'view_display'),
    );   
  }
}
```

You say it's better to not write PHP for maintenance reasons. I would argue the exact opposite - it's much easier to version control code than it is configuration stored in the DB.

Comment: I have added view header and footer content before, but in this case there's a lot of extra content which I'd like to be editable without editing the view. As for adding PHP, I'm fine with coding, but I try to avoid adding custom code when an existing module will suffice. So I'm asking for a comparison of the modules. Sorry I wasn't clearer.

Comment: @DanHalbert - Ok, I see your point. In that case what about [EVA](https://www.drupal.org/project/eva) or [Insert View](https://www.drupal.org/project/insert_view)

Comment: EVA is yet another choice - thanks - I added it in the question. Given all the modules I listed in the question, is there some reason to choose one over the other? For instance, do some inhibit caching, or not handle permissions properly? Or is one conceptually better? I am faced with wood screws, machine screws, nails, glue, etc. Which one is the best choice for this situation? Or is it just twelve kinds of peanut butter?

Comment: I've not got experience with any of those modules. If I was you I would install each of them and have a quick play and see how well it does what you want. Then just pick the best one. I'm not sure if your going to find someone here who is able to tell you which is best, and even then what may be best for their exact use case may differ from yours...